# form of symmetric matrix of rank one

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question is:

Let $C$ be a symmetric matrix of rank one. Prove that $C$ must have the form $C=aww^T$, where $a$ is a scalar and $w$ is a vector of norm one.

I think we can easily prove that if $C$ has the form $C=aww^T$, then $C$ is symmetric and of rank one. Why we need $w$ is of norm one?

Comment: If a matrix is rank-one, all its columns are  multiple of each other. This implies the matrix has the form $C_{ij}=a_ib_j$. Since $C$ is assumed symmetric, we can also choose $a_i=b_i$.

Answer (score 8):

$C$ is a symmetric matrix and thus has eigen decomposition $C=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\lambda_iu_iu_i^H$. If it is rank one, all eigenvalues except one will be zero, thus $C=\lambda uu^H$ where $\lambda$ is the non-zero eigenvalue and $u$ is the corresponding unit norm eigen vector.

Comment: Hi @dineshdileep, in this formula, $C=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\lambda_iu_iu_i^H$, suppose $C$ is symmetric positive definite, so, can N be less than the rank of $C$ ?. Could we have an approximation of the form $C=\sum_{i=1}^{r}\lambda_iu_iu_i^T$, where $r << N$?

Comment: $N$ is the dimension of matrix $C$ and $C$ will have $N$ eigenvalues. Now $r$ of them can be non-zero and others being zero will allow what you want. You might be interested in principal component analysis and low rank approximation literature. For instance, there are theorems on the closest $k-$ rank approximation. For instance, the closest rank-one approximation to $C$ will be the rank one matrix $\lambda_1 u_1 u_1^H$ corresponding to the largest eigenvalue (assuming positive definite $C$) and so on and so forth.

Comment: Thank you @dineshdileep

Comment: I have another related question. In the case of low rank approximation, can we use von Neumann divergence to measure the goodness of the fit between the two parts ?

Answer (score 6):

dineshdileep has already provided what is perhaps the natural solution to this problem. Let me present another.

Any matrix has what is called a [rank factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization). In the case of a rank $1$ matrix, every row in the matrix is a multiple of some specific row. Let $\mathbf{y}$ be that row and let $\mathbf{x}$ be the vector of multiples associated with $\mathbf{y}$. Then $A$ naturally factors as 
$$A=\mathbf{x}\mathbf{y}^\mathrm{T}$$
We may factor out the magnitudes to get 
$$A = \|\mathbf{x}\|\|\mathbf{y}\|\,\mathbf{\hat{x}}\mathbf{\hat{y}}^\mathrm{T}$$
So far this decomposition holds for *any* matrix, symmetric or not. Our goal now is to prove that $\mathbf{x} = \pm\mathbf{y}$ in the case of symmetry.

Suppose then that $A$ is symmetric with decomposition $A = c\mathbf{x}\mathbf{y}^\mathrm{T}$ where $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are unit vectors. By symmetry, we get
$$\mathbf{x}\mathbf{y}^\mathrm{T} = \mathbf{y}\mathbf{x}^\mathrm{T}$$
Multiplying on the left by $\mathbf{y}^\mathrm{T}$ and on the right by $\mathbf{x}$, we get
$$1=\|\mathbf{x}\|^2\|\mathbf{y}\|^2 = (\mathbf{x}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{x})(\mathbf{y}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{y}) = \mathbf{x}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{y}\mathbf{x}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{y} = (\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{y})^2$$
which of course implies
$$|\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{y}| = 1 = \|\mathbf{x}\|\|\mathbf{y}\|$$
This is the equality case of Cauchy-Schwarz, which holds if and only if $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are linearly dependent. The two are both unit vectors so it follows that $\mathbf{x} = \pm\mathbf{y}$. Therefore we have
$$A = \pm c \mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^\mathrm{T}$$
as required.

Comment: were you out of MSE for a while? was missing your insightful answers for some time.

Comment: @dineshdileep Well, I haven't been as active as I was before due to lack of time, but I've always been around. Thanks for asking!

Comment: In $A = \|\mathbf{x}\|\|\mathbf{y}\|\,\mathbf{\hat{x}}\mathbf{\hat{y}}^\mathrm{T}$, do $\mathbf{\hat{x}}$, $\mathbf{\hat{y}}$ represent unit vectors?

Comment: @Ian Yes, the hats represent unit vectors.