# If a matrix is of rank one, and let $v$ be the eigen vector corresponding the eigen value $d$. Then, $A=dvv^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If a symmetric matrix is of rank one, and let $v$ be the eigen vector corresponding the eigen value $d$.
Then, 
$$A=dvv^T$$

How to prove this??

Comment: $d$ needs to be normalized

Comment: And you need symmetry. Consider $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @user251257 Thank you..for the observation

Answer (score 0):

[We know that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/359688/152030) a symmetric matrix $A$ of rank $1$ can be written in the form $A = a a^T$ (where $a$ is a column vector).

Let $d$ be a non-zero<sup>1</sup> eigenvalue of $A$, and $v$ a corresponding eigenvector. Then
\begin{align*}
A v & = d v \implies\\
a a^T v & = d v \implies\\
a & = \dfrac{d}{a^T v} v
\end{align*}

But then $a^T = \dfrac{d}{a^T v} v^T \implies a^T v = \dfrac{d}{a^T v} v^T v \implies (a^T v)^2 = d \| v \|^2 \implies a^T v = \pm \sqrt d \, \| v \|$. Therefore, $a = \pm \dfrac{\sqrt d}{\| v \|} v$, and thus from $A = aa^T$, we have
\begin{equation*}
A = \dfrac{d}{\| v \|^2} v v^T.
\end{equation*}

In particular, if $v$ is normalized, then $A = d\, v v^T$.

---

<sup>1</sup> We know that $A$ has a non-zero eigenvalue since $A$ is a diagonalizable matrix (being symmetric) and has rank $1$. For, if all eigenvalues of $A$ were zero, then $A$ would be similar to the zero matrix (from the diagonalization), and hence be the zero matrix itself.