# How do I find the transformed vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two vectors $$x = [-2, 3, 4]^T\\y = [1, -2, 2]^T$$ $A$ is a 3 x 3 matrix that is symmetric. Rank of $A$ is 1. We know that $$Ax = [4, -6, -8]^T$$ Now I'm supposed to find out vector $Ay$.

I have approached this problem in the following way. I can see that $Ax$ is just $-2*x$, which means $x$ is an eigen vector of $A$ with eigen value $\lambda = -2$. Because rank is 1, other 2 eigen values are 0. Now looking at thin Singular Value Decomposition of $A$, if $A = U \Sigma V^T$, then I essentially have $$x = U = [-2, 3, 4]^T\hspace{0.2cm} and \hspace{0.2cm} \Sigma = [-2]$$ So the only thing I lack now is $V^T$. Now I'm stuck at this point. Can anyone help me figure out how to move forward or if this is the right way to go about for solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal, $Ay$ must be $0$. This is because, by the spectral theorem,
$$\mathbb{R}^3 = E_{-2} \oplus E_0,$$
where $E_{-2}$ and $E_0$ are the two eigenspaces.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't understand spectral theorem or other fancy mathematics in linear algebra. I'm a software engineer. Is there another, more intuitive, reason why $Ay$ must be $0$?

Comment: @SamvidMistry In that case you need to give some context because that problem seems tailored for the spectral theorem.

Comment: It is unlikely that this problem should require the use of Spectral theorem. This question is provided to us in a machine learning course as part of linear algebra exercises and we are not taught Spectral theorem. We are only taught basic linear algebra with ranks, eigen value, eigen vectors SVD and PCA.

Comment: Doesn't PCA rely on the spectral theorem, though? Anyway, maybe this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359604/form-of-symmetric-matrix-of-rank-one

Comment: According to the provided link, I have written $A = -2xx^T$, now doing $Ay$ does give $\textbf{0}$ vector as answer. But my confusion is that after constructing $A$ this way, when I do $Ax$, it gives $[116,-174,-232]^T$, which can be converted to $[4,-6,-8]^T$ by factoring out 29 from vector. Shouldn't it just return $[4,-6,-8]^T$ as the answer, if this is perfect reconstruction of $A$? Sorry if my questions are dumb.

Comment: @SamvidMistry You need to divide by $\|x\|^2$ because you are supposed to use unit vectors. If you do, you get the right answer.

Comment: That solves it perfectly. Thank you so much.